# Request Attributes are lost during forwarding from one Servlet to another Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, war

In my web application I have 2 `servlets` where one pass data to another. Please check the below code.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoadCategoryList");
            request.setAttribute("save_result", result);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In this code I am passing data `save_result` to `LoadCategoryList`. Below is how I try to collect this data in `LoadCategoryList`

```
String result = request.getParameter("save_result");
```

Anyway, the passed data seems to be `NULL`. But I can GUARANTEE that data I am passing are not `NULL`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request parameters and request attributes are two different things.

If you set a value using [`ServletRequest.setAttribute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), you have to retrieve it using [`ServletRequest.getAttribute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)).

Comment: sessions will be maintained only if the cookies are available & runs on same JVM if I'm correct. The better way to pass data between dispatches must be parameters rather than attributes?

Comment: @Kris It's a request attribute, not a session attribute.